# Binary classification for web pages

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification

We are interested in doing binary classification of web pages present across the web e.g. Ecommerce vs Non-Ecommerce.

Currently, we are using Mahout library with Naive Bayes algorithm. We are creating training data from existing classified URLs and feature set from the same.

What is the best possible way in terms of accuracy to perform this task?

I need help in terms of algorithm, libraries(usable with JAVA) or any better ideas that help in such types of classification.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is quite general so I can add only general information.

The ways to improve the quality of your classification are (in order of importance):

- use Lemmatisation and/or [Stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) to use only base word forms
- implement word filter to remove useless words
- train separate classifiers for different languages

Comment: There are other web-page specific normalization... e.g. replace all email with "EMAIL", all your domain name with the "DOMAIN", etc... Just find-and-replace. This is how CRM114 works.

Comment: @andrey We are already doing a)Stemming and b)Stop word removal.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use some existing, well-tuned program,...

[CRM411](http://crm114.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php) is designed to be a spam filter, but it is generic enough to do what you want. People use it to sort resume and stuffs. It have lots of engine (HMM, SVM, CLUMP, Bayes, etc..). Give it a try.

Comment: Do you have any idea about relative comparison between different libraries and algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

[This one](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/naive-bayes-text-classification-1.html) is a very good demonstration of the algorithm regarding NB classifier.

Discarding most common words would lead to better predictions. [IDF](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/inverse-document-frequency-1.html) can be a good tool for filtering out those words. Also see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf).